# OGR Merge split part of basename

Tags: shapefile, ogr

```
ogrmerge.py -single -o merged3.shp *.shp -src_layer_field_content {DS_BASENAME}
```

let's me painless merge several shapefiles into one and adds a new field with the basename of the shapefile. Is it possible to only write the first 9 characters of the basename to the shapefile?

**Is:**

2938_9282_myfile

**should**

2938_9282

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - the templating in `ogrmerge.py` looks to do a simple replacement and I don't see a way to put any more logic into it. A rewrite of chunks of `ogrmerge.py` would be necessary to extend the syntax to something like `{DS_BASENAME:1:9}`.

I think the easiest way would be use ogrmerge and then post-process it to fix the fields you want to change (with some python code, or load the .dbf into a spreadsheet program....).